# How to replace .env value into my url (using laravel 5.5)

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I want to replace value which is present in env file and my value is

```
 api_url=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

and my url where i want to replace this api_url  to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

```
 case 'S3bucketupload':
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload_aws';
```

other one is:

```
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/aweber_lists
```

i somehow want to add replace 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' to api_url which is present in .env. 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: please edit here with your answer url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/aweber_lists

Answer (score 0):

You can access `env` variables like this:

```
env('API_URL')
```

and have this in your `.env`:

```
API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

So in your case it would be:

```
case 'S3bucketupload':
        return env('API_URL') . '/api/upload_aws';
```

I would advise to add it to a config file such as `config/app.php` and something like:

```
api_url => env('API_URL', 'DEFAULT_VALUE')
```

The `DEFAULT_VALUE` is used if the variable is not found in the `.env` file

And then use it like this:

```
case 'S3bucketupload':
        return config('app.api_url') . '/api/upload_aws';
```

Have a look at this for more help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'S3bucketupload':
        return env('api_url');
```

For best practice use Config class:

.env

```
API_URL=http://XXXX.XX
```

config/api.php

```
    return [
'url'=>env('API_URL')
]
```

Call it as follwing

```
case 'S3bucketupload':
            return Config::get('api.url');
```